# Facebook Requests Dialog: Frictionless Requests in native iOS app possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, dialog, apprequests

As of Oct 10, 2011, the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) does again support the "apprequests" dialog for sending user-to-user requests from native iOS apps (see the [screenshots in Facebook's developer docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/screenshots/ios/#iphone-native) for an example).

One thing that's missing compared to the apprequests dialog invoked via Javascript, though, is the possibility to enable the so-called [frictionless requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) (see the section about frictionless requests about halfway down the page), i.e. the ability for the user to allow the app to send user-to-user requests without the dialog popping up every time by checking a checkbox when the dialog pops up first.

Question: is there a way to enable frictionless requests for native iOS apps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer my own question, frictionless requests now work (as of late Oct 2011). It seems Facebook has enabled the functionality.

The reason it worked all of sudden might also have to do with us switching our FB app ID from a sandbox app (for internal testing) to an app used in production. So perhaps frictionless requests are enabled by Facebook only for production apps or on an app-by-app basis.

Answer (score 2):

The SDK references still claim it's not possible.

"You cannot use frictionless requests in native iOS or Android apps, or from any server-side SDKs."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: Yes, the doc is incorrect, that is, out of date. It does work.