# Frictionless Requests on iOS - how?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, apprequests, facebook-ios-sdk

How do you enable frictionless requests in the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)? I saw [Ole Begemann's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751806/facebook-requests-dialog-frictionless-requests-in-native-ios-app-possible) that it now "just works", but I get the request dialog every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frictionless requests can be turned on by setting the "frictionless" parameter of the apprequests dialog to "1".  For example;

```
// create a dictionary for our dialog's parameters
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity: 7];

// set the frictionless requests parameter to "1"
[params setObject: @"1" forKey:@"frictionless"];

// ... add other parameters ...

// show the request dialog
[facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params andDelegate: nil];
```

This also answers [Facebook IOS SDK Frictioless Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8447935/1077258)

Comment: It really was that simple. Thanks a lot, David!