# iOS - Send requests to Facebook friends

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I have been trying to set up a system on my app, where users can send requests to their Facebook friends. I followed the instructions on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/), and found that it presents a dialog where I can select friends and send invites. So far so good. But what I would like is that this dialog comes with the friends pre-selected so the users don't have to select them one by one. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation,

> You can filter the suggested list down or target one user. To filter down the list you can pass in a parameter, **suggestions** that contains a comma-separated list of friends to show in the selection. To target one recipient, pass that user's ID in a **to** parameter.

Comment: So you mean I set up an NSDictionary object with key @"to" and value "user-id" to send to a particular user?

Comment: Yes. Edited the answer pls check

Comment: Thanks! It worked. :) Also, is there a way to send these requests automatically without the user having to do it explicitly?

Comment: I think yes, this might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447935/facebook-ios-sdk-frictionless-requests